# Spring boot not run ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

for no reasons I cannot start spring boot app cause this log, I dont know where to repair it, I have only baic SpringBootApplication on app anotation thats all, basic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM58W.jpg)

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-25 20:54:39.204 ERROR 6404 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/petmik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration due to org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseType not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE] .................
```

Comment: Can you add your main class implementation and the POM.XML file ?

Comment: i solved problem maybe some collisions in old m2 jars in repository, indexing and metadata in Eclipse, i wrote it down

Answer (score 0):

It seems you havent mentioned datasource configuration. Spring Boot is not able to auto-configure a DataSource. To do so,  add some properties to application.properties with the spring.datasource prefix.

Refer [DataSourceProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) for all properties that you can set.

You'll need to provide the appropriate url and driver class name:

```
 spring.datasource.url = …
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name = …
```

Comment: nothing works, i deleted all indexes in metadatain Eclipse, cause big mess in developing, created new spring project, deleted all maven repo jars, copied classes and resources to new project, and Im surprised app now start in 2 seconds opposite 10s previously, work for 15 minutes whole, problem solved :-D